# Send differing HTTP headers for (non) preflight requests?

Tags: security, http-headers

for my web application, I'm configuring a set of [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/List_of_useful_HTTP_headers) security headers, like `X-Frame-Options` or `X-Content-Type-Options`. Now I'm wondering whether I should send all those headers for *every* request, or if I should use them only for specific requests, e.g., use the "full" bunch of security headers for get, post, delete, put, and send only CORS headers for preflight requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no harm in outputting the full security headers for each content type you serve (e.g. `text/html`, `application/java`) and for each request method (`GET`, `PUT`, etc).

However the ones that would be applicable for different requests and responses are discussed below.

Regarding returned content types:

- `X-Content-Type-Options` especially needs to be on all content types, as otherwise types such as `application/java` could be interpreted differently by Internet Explorer with its content-sniffing.
- `X-Frame-Options` for all content types to stop them being framed, although this does not prevent them being loaded by other means (e.g. `<img>` tag).
- `X-XSS-Protection` added to HTML content types only should be enough.
- `Content-Security-Policy` for HTML content types only should be enough.

Regarding HTTP methods (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT` etc):

- `Strict-Transport-Security` is better if it is output on every request as it will renew the sliding expiration and it will also set the HSTS policy whichever way the resource was first requested.
- Public Key Pinning Extension for HTTP for every request, in much the same way as the `Strict-Transport-Security` header in that once it has been output, the policy will be set. As this is the sooner the better, if the site does this for all requests there is more chance of it being set earlier.